# Pandas Strip numbers from a string column in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in pandas which has string and numbers mixed
I want to strip numbers from the string.

```
A
11286011
11268163
C7DDA72897
C8ABC557
Abul
C80DAS577
C80DSS665
```

Want an output as

```
A
C7DDA72897
C8ABC557
Abul
C80DAS577
C80DSS665
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove non-numeric rows in one column with pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas select only numeric or integer field from dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883503/pandas-select-only-numeric-or-integer-field-from-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]:
            A
0    11286011
1    11268163
2  C7DDA72897
3    C8ABC557
4   C80DAS577
5   C80DSS665

In [53]: df = pd.to_numeric(df.A, errors='coerce').dropna()

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
0    11286011.0
1    11268163.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

or using RegEx:

```
In [59]: df.loc[~df.A.str.contains(r'\D+')]
Out[59]:
          A
0  11286011
1  11268163
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.str.isnumeric` to use in boolean slicing.

```
df[df.A.astype(str).str.isnumeric()]

          A
0  11286011
1  11268163
```

As pointed out by @MaxU, assuming every element is already a string, you can limit this to

```
df[df.A.str.isnumeric()]

          A
0  11286011
1  11268163
```

Comment: I think `A` is already of string (object) dtype, so we can omit `.astype(str)`...

Comment: @MaxU `dtype==object` doesn't imply that all elements are strings.  You can have an actual float or int in the array.  If you do, `str.isnumeric` will fail.

Comment: this is a good point! I just have tested it - `.isnumeric()` will retyren `NaN` in this case