# Pandas query- select tuples by unique column value and aggregate

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have two columns in a Pandas df that I would like to operate on. First, I would like to remove non-numeric values such as "High" from the column "score" and cast the remaining values as int (all data was input as strings). Next I would like to sum "score" based on unique "measure_id". How can I perform these two functions?

The df is:

```
nationwide_measures = pd.read_sql_query("""select state,
          measure_id,
          measure_name,
          score
from timely_and_effective_care___hospital;""", conn)
```

My failed attempt is:

```
 nationwide_measures1 = nationwide_measures.to_numeric(nationwide_measures{:,'score'}, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: what do you want the "score" to be after removing "high"? Do you want to remove the entire row?

Comment: Yes, if the score value is non-numeric- the tuple should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the nationwide_measure rows where the score value is numeric and I hope they are in the string format so convert them to `int` and then use `groupby` to aggregate the scores based on measure_id.

```
nationwide_measures1 = nationwide_measures[nationwide_measures['score'].str.isalpha() != True]
nationwide_measures1['score'] = pd.to_numeric(nationwide_measures1['score'])
score_sum = nationwide_measures1.groupby('measure_id')['score'].sum()
```

Hope this helps
Update: If you want sum,mean,min,max,std you can use .agg i.e

```
import numpy as np
score_sum = nationwide_measures1.groupby('measure_id')['score'].agg([pd.np.sum,pd.np.min, pd.np.max, pd.np.mean, pd.np.std])
```

Comment: The only problem is that there are other string values that need to be removed as well. I need to amend your suggestion with something like "!= .isalpha()" Any thoughts?

Comment: "AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'isaplha'"

Comment: That ran without a stack trace but the dataframe is still the same size.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Upon closer inspection, the score_sum values were a concatenation of the actual string values, not their sum. Your answer does not convert the 'score' values to int, which is what I need to do before I can apply the min,max,avg,stdev functions on the df

Comment: Yes, next I would like to compute the min, max, average, and stdev for each measure- can you help with that?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer to deleting tuples with non-numeric score values is:

```
nationwide_measures1 = nationwide_measures[nationwide_measures['score'].astype(str).str.isdigit()]
```

I found it here:
[Pandas select only numeric or integer field from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883503/pandas-select-only-numeric-or-integer-field-from-dataframe)